# How to create an SQS client for localhost use only

Tags: java, localhost, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I've got the following client instantiation code that works when deployed to AWS:

*pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.888</version>
</dependency>
```

*application.properties*

```ini
aws.sqs.endpoint=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

*SQSConfiguration.java*

```java
public AmazonSQS buildAWSClient() {
    String region = getRegionFromHost(endpoint.getHost());
    return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
}
```

Now, I want a client for accessing a local SQS endpoint (e.g. [ElasticMQ](https://github.com/softwaremill/elasticmq)).

*application.properties*

```ini
aws.sqs.endpoint=http://localhost:9300
```

*SQSConfiguration.java*

```java
public AmazonSQS buildLocalClient() {
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("not-a-real-key", "not-a-real-secret");
    return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint.toString(), Regions.DEFAULT_REGION.getName()))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();

}
```

However, when running the application I get the following error:

```
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SQS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: 68c103c1-b848-5cb9-8bbc-5bd2035aa586; Proxy: null)
```

I would like a developer to be able to pull this code and run it locally without needing to setup anything in their profile, pass environmental variables, etc.

**Can I, and if so how do I, setup the AWS client in a way that doesn't require AWS connectivity/permissions?**